# Is XEX/XTS good for deterministic file encryption?

Tags: encryption, modes-of-operation, xts

My understanding about XEX/XTS mode is limited. But from what I see, it has two good properties:

1. It is length-preserving so that encryption doesn't cost additional space.
2. It is deterministic, which is (usually bad but could be) a requirement in some use cases.

Assuming space is a scarce resource, encryption must be deterministic, while authentication is unnecessary, would XEX/XTS mode be a great choice for normal file encryption?

(A file is a byte stream, but we can impose offset-based virtual sectors on the stream and use these sector numbers in XEX/XTS algorithm.)

Comment: XTS / XEX were designed with an additional constraint in mind: Only requiring one block cipher call ($\pm$ on average) per data block. There are better modes that require two block calls, but this has been deemed "too slow" for most disk encryption SW.

Comment: @SEJPM Do you mean "wide-block" ones such as CMC and EME? What exactly makes them "better"?

Comment: yes, the fact that a single bit change randomizes more bytes, yielding better poor man's authentication.

Comment: @SEJPM That would make sense. Back to our topic, would there be other issues if we borrow a disk encryption algorithm (either XTS or CMC) for byte stream encryption?